# keeping my columns after summarise function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to retrieve 4 datas from a data set (Agegroup, HaveKids (Boolean), Wage, Expenses) and I want to create another table grouping Age Group and haveKids and having the average wage and expenses. After using summarize, my column haveKids was removed. I tried using ungroup() but I am still unable to see the column. May I ask why the ungroup function doesn't work?

```
ab_final <- ab %>%
  group_by(agegroup,haveKids) %>%
  summarise(Wage = mean(Wage), Expenses = mean(Expenses)) %>%
  summarise (Wage = ifelse(haveKids == "TRUE", yes = -Wage, no = Wage), Expenses = ifelse(haveKids == "TRUE", yes = Expenses, no = -Expenses)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

How could I do this better?

Comment: You probably need `mutate`? Also in if statements, there is no need for testing if `TRUE == TRUE`. In your case you have "TRUE" as a string, maybe make it an actual boolean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `summarise` only once. Otherwise, the last grouping (haveKids) in your case, will be removed. Just do

```
ab %>%
  group_by(agegroup,haveKids) %>%
  summarise(Wage = mean(Wage), Expenses = mean(Expenses)) %>%
  mutate(Wage = ifelse(haveKids, -Wage, Wage))
```

This will give you mean Wage and Expenses per every combination of agegroup and haveKids. You can use `mutate` afterwards to invert values conditionally.